# Could not find appropriate mongod in `D:\MMSData\MongoDBReleases

Tags: ops-manager

I have Opsmanager with 3 nodes [Windows version 4.2] . Backup Daemon running on two nodes. When I switch backup daemon from one node to another node my resync failing with below error message:

class com.xgen.svc.brs.job.ApplyOpsJob => ERROR backup.jobs.M1ReplicaSet [ReplicaSetJob.java.startMongo:139] - Failed to start mongod

com.xgen.svc.brs.util.AbstractMongoManager$MongodVersionException: Could not find appropriate mongod in `D:\MMSData\MongoDBReleases`, versions available to MMS: . Expecting version 3.2.1 or greater, module preference: enterprisePreferred

But I have binaries in zip format on both node

Regards

Naga